# MPI message availability notification

Tags: sockets, parallel-processing, signals, ipc, mpi

Is there a way in MPI to be notified of availability of message for a particular process? Currenlty I use polling with an asynchronous MPI_Iprobe followed by an MPI_Recv . This means the process have to stop what it is doing and call this method now and then. Is there a way to be notified for availability of message through signals/interrupts?  Another option is to do this polling stuff with a separate thread but I am not sure if that is acceptable because it consumes  cpu time.

```
    int poll(int& source,int& message_id) {
     int flag;
     MPI_Status mpi_status;
     MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&flag,&mpi_status);
     if(flag) {
       message_id = mpi_status.MPI_TAG;
       source = mpi_status.MPI_SOURCE;
       return true;
     }
     return false;
    }
```

---

**Edit:**  It looks like MPI implementations use polling http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/polling-vs-blocking-message-passingprogress/

The best solution for this seems to be using the blocking MPI_Probe() and then 
   mpirun -n 2 --mca yield_when_idle
This will make the polling threads to block until message is sent. But some mpi implementations do not have the mca option.

Comment: Could you describe what you are really trying to do? I believe there might be a better solution.

Comment: Multithreaded use of MPI requires an implementation that provides `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` thread support level. Open MPI provides it if compiled accordingly but then it cannot use native InfiniBand communication if available on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a mechanism is not directly available in a portable way.

You could use a thread with `MPI_Wait` (or a flavor thereof) - or even more simply `MPI_Recv`. However there is no guarantee that your MPI implementation doesn't consume CPU while waiting on the message. (While it is guaranteed that polling over `MPI_Iprobe` will indeed consume 100% CPU.) Also be careful with MPI and threads, there are pitfalls and different operating modes.

Why would you want to do that in the first place? There may be a better mechanism for what you do, for instance using one-sided communication.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a two sided communication with different type of messages that are sent in no particular order. First I have to check what message it is, then allocate the appropriate data structure to recieve it.

Comment: Then you couldn't do it in a signal handler anyway, it's not signal-safe to allocate memory.

Comment: It is pre-allocated on the stack so that is not a problem. But I need to know what type of message it is before receiving it. Most messages are simple notifications of MPI_INTEGER type, while others messages contain variable number of bytes.  The problem I am trying to solve is a tree search on a cluster.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this paper: http://www.unixer.de/publications/index.php?pub=103 It discusses how multithreaded applications can receive messages of unknown size. `MProbe` was implemented in MPI 3.0

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a good paper. They mentioned that for MPI 2.2, the polling method as I have it now or by using threads is the only option.